# Работа с элементом DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не знаю, правильно ли я охарактеризовал свой вопрос, но суть такова:
Есть структура

```
<div class="row">
<span>Example</span><input id="last_name" class="validate valid">
</div>
```

Ищу input так: при клике на example вызываю `$(this).parents('div.row').find('input#last_name.validate.valid');`
Как присвоить `input'у` класс `invalid`?

this это `example` - т.е. `span`

Comment: $(this) - span?

Comment: где именно вызывается этот код? что такое `this`?

Comment: а что у вас $(this) ? вы с чего начинаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вводных явно маловато, но предположу, что одновременно и valid и invalid быть не может, пускай будет такой вариант:

```js
$('span').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.validate').toggleClass('valid invalid');
});
```

```css
.validate.valid {
  border-color: green;
}

.validate.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <span>Example</span>
 <input id="last_name" class="validate valid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При данной разметке, достаточно смотреть на следующий элемент относительно того, на который кликнули и делать с ним манипуляции

```js
$('.row').on('click', 'span', function(){
  $(this).next('input').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin:10px;
}

.valid {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example</span>
  <input id="last_name" class="validate valid">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example2</span>
  <input id="last_name2" class="validate valid">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example3</span>
  <input id="last_name3" class="validate valid">
</div>
```

---

Небольшой toggle

```js
$('.row').on('click', 'span', function(){
  var input = $(this).next('input');    
  input.toggleClass('valid invalid');
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin:10px;
}

.valid {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example</span>
  <input id="last_name" class="validate valid">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example2</span>
  <input id="last_name2" class="validate valid">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Example3</span>
  <input id="last_name3" class="validate valid">
</div>
```